# Drawing and redrawing an image to simulate animation doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I have a simple animation which shows a gas meter moving from green to red. I am simply drawing, clearing and then redrawing the image on a timer to try and simulate animation. Although it kind of works, the animation lags and sometimes just goes back and forward after it should have been completed.

Heres the code:

```
function meter(){
        requestAnimationFrame(meter);

        setTimeout(function() {

        var radius = 40;
        ctx.clearRect(500, 200, 100, 100);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(550, 250, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.4)';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffcc4a";
        ctx.fillRect(525, 220, 50, 60);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.fillRect(528, 225, 44, 45);


        var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(510, 0, 670, 0);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
        grd.addColorStop(0.25, "yellow");
        grd.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fillRect(530, 228, 40, 30);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.arc(550, 264, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.moveTo(549, 260);
            ctx.lineTo(548, 240);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();


        ctx.closePath();
        //ctx.clearRect(500, 200, 100, 100);    

            }, 2000);

            setTimeout(function() {

        var radius = 40;
        ctx.clearRect(500, 200, 100, 100);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(550, 250, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.4)';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffcc4a";
        ctx.fillRect(525, 220, 50, 60);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.fillRect(528, 225, 44, 45);


        var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(510, 0, 670, 0);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
        grd.addColorStop(0.25, "yellow");
        grd.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fillRect(530, 228, 40, 30);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.arc(550, 264, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.moveTo(549, 260);
            ctx.lineTo(558, 240);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();


        ctx.closePath();
        //ctx.clearRect(500, 200, 100, 100);    

            }, 2500);

            setTimeout(function() {

        var radius = 40;
        ctx.clearRect(500, 200, 100, 100);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(550, 250, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.4)';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffcc4a";
        ctx.fillRect(525, 220, 50, 60);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.fillRect(528, 225, 44, 45);


        var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(510, 0, 670, 0);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
        grd.addColorStop(0.25, "yellow");
        grd.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fillRect(530, 228, 40, 30);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.arc(550, 264, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.moveTo(549, 260);
            ctx.lineTo(568, 240);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();


        ctx.closePath();
        //ctx.clearRect(500, 200, 100, 100);    

            }, 3000);   



    }
```

Comment: You need to remove the setTimeout function that you have. What happens now is that with requestAnimationFrame(), you're asking your browser if it's ready to render and he'll say yes!, and you'll start a 3 second timer to animate. The problem is that since you're not drawing anything for 3 seconds, you'll keep asking your browser if it's ready to draw, quite often, and you'll and up with a lot of animation requests that will not fire with 3 second delay, more likely within milliseconds.

Comment: Hi @Niddro can you give any more hints as to what i would need to add in place of the setTimeout function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you'll have enough time to call the requestAnimationFrame function a bunch of times while the first setTimeout funtions are waiting to fire and draw stuff. This mean that you'll probably end up starting the setTimeout timers a few houndred times before the first one fires.

This is basically what you have:

```
function meter(){
    requestAnimationFrame(meter);

    setTimeout(function() {
        //drawing stuff
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        //drawing stuff
    }, 2500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        //drawing stuff
    }, 3000);   
}
```

You're drawing the same thing three times with one small change. Instead, make it into 1 function with a parameter:

```
function meter(indicatorPosition){
    //black circle
    var radius = 40;
    ctx.clearRect(500, 200, 100, 100);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(550, 250, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.4)';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.stroke();

    //yellow rectangle
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffcc4a";
    ctx.fillRect(525, 220, 50, 60);
    //white rectangle over yellow
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.fillRect(528, 225, 44, 45);

    //meter gradient background
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(510, 0, 670, 0);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
    grd.addColorStop(0.25, "yellow");
    grd.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(530, 228, 40, 30);

    //circle and indicator
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.arc(550, 264, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.moveTo(549, 260);
    ctx.lineTo(indicatorPosition, 240); //this is the only variable!
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Now to make it move:

if you want it to move every 0.5 seconds, it's better to use the setInterval.

```
var meterPosition = 548 //your starting position
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    //each run we draw the meter
    meter(meterPosition);
    //Then we want to add 10 to the meter position
    meterPosition+=10;
    //We don't want the meter to go nuts and disappear to the right, so we'll make it reset after 3 moves
    if (meterPosition > 568) {
        meterPosition = 548;
    }
},500);
```

Here's a fiddle with the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/7jxknwk4/

Comment: excellent, thanks alot. If i wanted to just stop the indicator at 568, could i just use the stop() function?

Comment: Yes, infact you stop the interval by using the function clearInterval(); on your interval variable, like so: `clearInterval(myInterval);`

Comment: Could this be done using setTimeout instead? I have other animations within this one that uses setInterval and i think that they may be intefering with each other.

Comment: Each animation should be controlled using its own interval variable (`var intervalOne, intervalTwo;`) etc. Then you can cancel each animation individually: `clearInterval(intervalTwo);` allowing the other animation(s) to keep going.